# How do you query data using Mongoose within a service function?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemailer

I have a service in my node application where I am trying to use nodemailer to send an email with a link to clients. The issue I am having is that when I try to query the recipient email address using Mongoose in the service I get this response message in the console log `Promise { <pending> }` and obviously my email does not send because I am not returning an email address. I am using the code below as the service that is called from my controller. It looks like everything is working fine in the controller because when I use a test email address as the recipient email the message is sent and function returns no errors. Am I writing the function to query the email wrong or is there a better way I should be setting this up?

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Obrf = require("../models/Obrf");

const sendLink = (x) => {
    var id = x;
    const offerid = id.toString();
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/offerletter/' + offerid
    
    async function returnEmail (y) {
        const email = await Obrf.findById(y, 'email_address').exec();
        return email;
    };

    const sendToEmail = returnEmail(id);

    console.log(sendToEmail);

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'sender@gmail.com',
          pass: 'password'
        }
      });
      
      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'sender@gmail.com',
        to: sendToEmail,
        subject: 'Congratulations on your offer!',
        text: 'Go to: ' + url + ' to sign your offer letter!'
      };
      
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });
};

module.exports = {
    sendLink,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

async before a function makes the function return a promise:

are you sure if `Obrf.findById(y, 'email_address').exec()` returning promise ?

if not remove the aysnc await

```
  function returnEmail (y) {
        const email =  Obrf.findById(y, 'email_address').exec();
        return email;
    };

    const sendToEmail = returnEmail(id);
```

if its returning the promise then do something like this

```
 const sendToEmail = returnEmail(id).then(id=>id);
```